# How to read the content of a BIM 360 file as a filestream and writes it to another stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I was looking into this document
[AutoDesk](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/hubs/netcore)
I am able to get Files/Folders structure and content from BIM 360 but is there a way I can read the content of a file as file stream to write it in different file(I don't want to download the file locally) in .Net core without using rest end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getObject](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#getobject) method (from the official Forge SDK) that is typically used to access OSS data (which BIM 360 Docs uses under the hood as well) does return `System.IO.Stream` already. So you should be able to stream the incoming data anywhere you need. For example, you can redirect the stream to another POST request as explained in this [tutorial](https://code-maze.com/using-streams-with-httpclient-to-improve-performance-and-memory-usage/):

```cs
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/some/endpoint");
    using (var requestContent = new StreamContent(stream))
    {
        request.Content = requestContent;
        using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to use Autodesk .net library to do read a file stream from BIM 360 Docs instead of using rest end point.

Comment: BIM 360 Docs is a cloud-based SaaS solution, so if you want to read a file (stream) from there, you *will* have to make an HTTP request. The Forge SDK for .NET Core makes that a little bit easier as it wraps the handling of the HTTP request and response in a simple method such as the [getObject](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#getobject) one mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a way to download model file from BIM 360 docs instead of original uploaded file?